# Connecting Android Device to Raspberry Pi using SSH

Tags: java, android, ssh, jsch

I am trying to connect to my `Raspberry Pi` using an android device. The application just shuts down without any `force close error` after i call the `connect()` method. I think my problem is session.connect(1000). Thanks in advance.

```
public void Connect() {
      JSch jsch = new JSch();
      try {

          jsch.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

          //open a new session
          session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port); // pi, 192.168.43.213, 22
          session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
          session.setPassword(password); //passwrord : raspberry

          tv.setText("Connecting");
          session.connect(1000); //connect session
          tv.setText("Connected");

      } catch (JSchException e) {
          tv.setText("JSchException");
          Toast t = Toast.makeText(ClientSSH.this, "Failed to Create Session or Timed Out", 1000);
          t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
          t.show();

      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the correct permissions in your Manifest.xml file for Network connectivity?
I know this is a comment really.

Comment: I added     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>